# Big variable in data structures

Tags: c, data-structures

I am new with data structures and c-language. I came across this algorithm

```
big=a
if(b>big)
  big = b
end if
if(c>big)
  big = c
end if
if(d>big)
  big =d
end if
return big
```

does this statement mean that "'if' statement will end if big=b in situation of b being greater then big(or a as a=big) and henceforth.

also i wanted to know what is big as a variable used for and what it means as came across big-o and big-theta in data structures. thnx in advance

Comment: That's not C ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above algorithm returns you the largest number among  a,b,c,d. It has nothing to do with  Big O and theta as these are related to complexities of an algorithm.